# Why the empty set is the only open of measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal M,m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Why the empty set is the only open of measure zero ? I saw in a proof, since $m(O)=0$ and that $O$ is open, then $O=\emptyset$, but I don't understand this last implication.

Answer (score 3):

Every non-empty open set $G$ contains a ball of some positive radius around each $x \in G$, and an open ball with positive radius has non zero Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\mathcal O\neq\emptyset$ is an open set s.t. $m(\mathcal O)=0$. Let $x\in \mathcal O$. By definition, there is $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $]x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon[\subset \mathcal O$, and thus $m(\mathcal O)>\varepsilon$ which contradict the fact that $m(\mathcal O)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is open and non empty, it contains a $\sup$ norm ball of radius $\epsilon$, that is
$B_\infty(x,\epsilon) \subset U$ for some $x\in U$.

Since $m B_\infty(x,\epsilon) = (2\epsilon)^d >0$, we see that $m U > 0$.